# Not getting user dialed number in Android 9.0 Even i have declared both Read call log and REad Phone State permission at Runtime as well

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

In my app I am trying to intercept all outgoing calls starting with 00 string. I used Telephony Manager for the same to get outgoing number and then intercept it. All code was working properly before Android 9.0. But in Android Pie once i made call then my app crashed because i am not getting User Dialed number in  Receiver.

Comment: Put some code here.

Comment: All below permissions are given in Manifest and Runtime both place.
android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Answer (score 0):

> "Without the READ_CALL_LOG permission, however, the phone number field
>   that's provided in PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcasts and through
>   PhoneStateListener is empty."

So you have to ensure the user grants permission for reading phone number before you try to access any dialed number.
Also you have to keep a check and a backup plan in case user refuses permission. Your app should handle such case well so as to avoid any null pointers.

Comment: I am already using all these permissions in Manifest file also checked them at run time for requesting permission. Please check my code for Runtime permission.

Manifest Declarations:-

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Applied Runtime permission as well. Everything working in all versions except 9.0.